# How to upload large files in parts? without changing php.ini

Tags: php

This is my code:

```
//Receive the data from android
$name = $_POST['name'];

//Receive the file
$file = $_FILES['image'];

$uploadfile="Media/".$name;
if(is_uploaded_file($_FILES['image']['tmp_name'])) {
if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['image']['tmp_name'], $uploadfile)) {
 echo json_encode(
        array(
            'result'=>'success',
            'msg'=>'Media saved successfully.'
            )
        );
 }else{
     echo json_encode(
        array(
            'result'=>'The media can not be saved ',
            'msg'=>'Problems with the file.'
            )
        );
}
  }

?>
```

This works with files under 2 MB, and i dont want this limitation, also i dont want to change the php.ini(not because of me),so how i can send a large file in parts to the server?

Comment: 1. Modify your client-side JS code to break the file into chunks smaller than the 2MB limit. 2. Modify your server-side code to be aware of #1 and reconstruct the file.

Comment: Fixing this on the PHP side is preferable, since it'd be compatible with all clients regardless of javascript implementation.  A javascript-based workaround is desirable only as a last resort.

Answer (score 3):

You can temporarily override certain php.ini values using `ini_set()` (just for the lifetime of the request to your script): Is that acceptable to you?

http://php.net/manual/en/function.ini-set.php

Comment: Additionally, some ini values that can't be set using `ini_set()` can be set via .htaccess (these are labeled [PHP_INI_PERDIR](http://www.php.net/manual/en/configuration.changes.modes.php))

Comment: Seeing as you cannot set upload_max_filesize or post_max_size via ini_set(), the above comment seems more beneficial than this answer.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem because the hosting provider would not let me change the `php.ini`, but I fixed the problem using the `.user.ini` file, that you should create in the root folder of your domain. This file will look like `php.ini` but run locally (available since PHP 5.3). More information at http://php.net/manual/en/configuration.file.per-user.php

Then for example to upload up to 100MB, should write in `.user.ini`:

```
upload_max_filesize = 100M
post_max_size = 100M
memory_limit = 105M
```